# I need to change date format from dd-MM-yyyy to yyyy-MM-DD

Tags: java, postgresql, datetime

I want to change the date format before it goes to the database.

I have a calendar. And I am sending date from frontend in `dd-MM-yyyy` format.

When I send with this format: `yyyy-MM-dd` everything works well. But I need `dd-MM-yyyy`

I am using PostgreSQL and I have an attribute to store the date in timestamp with time zone format

> For example: my date in DB 2021-06-11 12:58:44.000000 +00:00

My rest controller

```
  @PutMapping("/edit")
  public void editTime(@RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
   //userDto.getTime() - has this format dd-MM-yyyy
   // I understand that i need to change format here. But i don't know how 
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse (userDto.getTime());
    Instant currentTime = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toInstant();
    userService.update(userDto.getId(),currentTime);
  }
```

Service method

```
public interface UserService {
  User update(String Id, Instant time);
}
```

Comment: Where exactly are you using a `String` formatted as `dd-MM-yyyy`? I cannot see any `String`... You are passing an `Instant` to your `userService`... That all comes quite confusing.

Comment: In my case userDto.getTime() is a String

Comment: Then why are you calling `userDto.getTime()`? Can you call that on a `String`? If the attribute `time` of a `UserDto` is a `String`, then use its setter along with a `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`: `userDto.setTime(date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu"))` (yes, `uuuu` instead of `yyyy`).

Comment: Another solution is to use [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) for sending between front-end and server, so `yyyy-MM-dd`, and then in the front-end convert to and from the format that the user likes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse (userDto.getTime(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"));
```

Hopefully this should work fine if you are passing in this "dd-MM-yyyy" format.

https://help.gooddata.com/cloudconnect/manual/date-and-time-format.html >> this is a good link for Java `DateTimeFormatter` patterns.

Comment: Good answer, just use `u` instead of `y` for the year...